# What is this attrib command saying?

Tags: windows, command-line

Could anyone tell me what this  command says?  I used this command when I couldn't find my files on my flash drive. but I don't know what it is saying, I only know `-h` and `-r` which remove the hidden and read-only attribute, respectively.

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DavidPostill's answer lists the meanings of all `attrib`'s switches. Let's use that to interpret that specific command:

- `-h` removes the hidden attribute (so the items will show up in Explorer)
- `-r` removes the read-only attribute
- `-s` removes the system attribute (also so the items will show up in Explorer)
- `/s` makes the command look in all subfolders recursively
- `/d` makes it apply the attributes to folders too (not just files)
- `g:\*.*` is the path to apply the changes on

So, I conclude that the command was meant to unset all attributes from everything on the G drive (`*.*` means all files with an extension; `*` is a wildcard that matches one or more characters. The `/s` makes it do everything in all folders under your starting directory, `g:\`.)

If you're trying to find a file, that command might make stuff show up in Explorer (assuming you're not showing hidden/system files anyway), but it won't magically tell you the location of whatever you're looking for. To find a specific file, try Explorer's search feature.

Comment: fantastic answer, I am satisfied pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

#### What does this command mean?

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*
```

Run `attrib /?` to get help:

```
F:\test>attrib /?
Displays or changes file attributes.

ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A ] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [+I | -I]
       [drive:][path][filename] [/S [/D] [/L]]

  +   Sets an attribute.
  -   Clears an attribute.
  R   Read-only file attribute.
  A   Archive file attribute.
  S   System file attribute.
  H   Hidden file attribute.
  I   Not content indexed file attribute.
  [drive:][path][filename]
      Specifies a file or files for attrib to process.
  /S  Processes matching files in the current folder
      and all subfolders.
  /D  Processes folders as well.
  /L  Work on the attributes of the Symbolic Link versus
      the target of the Symbolic Link
```

Notes:

- [attrib](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) goes into a lot more detail about the `attrib` command.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [attrib](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) - Display or change file attributes.